# How generate dynamic expression for date time filed in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to make a dynamic search for my class and I have a problem making a dynamic expression for DateTime Filed. My function is work for **string** or **int** property but I want to generate a dynamic expression for the date-time filed.
here is my class:

```csharp
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my function:

```csharp
private static BinaryExpression getSearchMethod(string Operator, MemberExpression Member, ConstantExpression Constant)
{
    BinaryExpression Body;

    if (Operator.Equals("=="))
    {
        Body = Expression.Equal(Member, Constant);
    }

    else if (Operator.Equals(">="))
    {
        Body = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(Member, Constant);
    }
    else if (Operator.Equals("<="))
    {
        Body = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(Member, Constant);
    }
    else if (Operator.Equals("!="))
    {
        Body = Expression.NotEqual(Member, Constant);
    }
    else if (Operator.Equals(">"))
    {
        Body = Expression.GreaterThan(Member, Constant);
    }
    else
    {
        Body = Expression.LessThan(Member, Constant);
    }

    return Body;
}
```

and for generating expression, I call this one

```csharp
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GeneretWhere<T>(T classModel)
{
    Type myType = classModel.GetType();
    IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(myType.GetProperties());
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
    {
        object propValue = prop.GetValue(classModel, null);
        LambdaExpression CompareExp;
        ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x"); // x
        MemberExpression Member = Expression.Property(param, prop.Name.ToString()); // x.Name
        ConstantExpression Constant = getConstariant(Member, propValue?.ToString() ?? ""); // =="value"
        if (Constant.Type == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            string propertyName = prop.Name;
            DateTime testDate = DateTime.Now;

            ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
            MemberExpression me = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
            var ce = Expression.Convert(me, typeof(DateTime?));
            var mc = Expression.Call(typeof(DbFunctions), null, Type.EmptyTypes, ce);

            ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(testDate, typeof(DateTime?));
            BinaryExpression body = Expression.Equal(mc, constant);
            var isEqualExpressionTree = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, new[] { parameter });

            BinaryExpression Body = getSearchMethod("==", Member, Constant);
            //---- x=>x.filed == value
            CompareExp = Expression.Lambda(Body, param);
            return (Expression<Func<T, bool>>) CompareExp;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

after these functions, the result is like some how this:

```csharp
(x=>x.RegistrationDate == DateTime.Naw)
```

but what should I do if I want the result is like this:

```csharp
(x=>x.RegistrationDate.Date == DateTime.Naw.Date)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You seem to be attempting to re-invent [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries)?

Comment: not actually re-invent. I want to generate LINQ in runtime at backend and my code work for string and int property but not for date-time property